# observ_field with collection_select on rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I'm developing project on rails 2.3.8 and I need to observe field on drop down menu which develop using collection select. Please can some one explain how to observe field ? 
My collection select code is like this

```
<%= collection_select("event", "trainer_id", @trainers , :id, :name, {:prompt => true}) %>
```

And I don't know how to use observe field for this. So please can some one explain about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related: [Auto populate a text field based on another text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665669/auto-populate-a-text-field-based-on-another-text-field)

```
observe_field(field_id, options = {})
```

Observes the field with the DOM ID specified by `field_id` and calls a callback when its contents have changed. The default callback is an Ajax call. By default the value of the observed field is sent as a parameter with the Ajax call.

Read this details: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/observe_field

Comment: Thanks for your reply can you please tell me how to put id on         <%= collection_select("event", "trainer_id", @trainers , :id, :name, {:prompt => true}) %>. Do I need to add id separately

Comment: No. The id would be "event_trainer_id".

Comment: Thanks it worked :). Can u pls tell me is it possible to use observe_field on model dialog box on rails ?